# Robolectric 2.3 - Test for support.Fragment Fails with "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme"

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm writing a test for a support.Fragment, but I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

Exception is thrown when I try to start the fragment (During activity creation):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AuthFragmentTest extends TestCase {   

    private SupportFragment fragment;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        fragment = new SupportFragment();

        FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment, SupportFragmentActivity.class);
    }
}
```

This is the API level Im using.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Also, Robolectric is configured to use the same Manifest as the application with /src/test/resources/org.robolectric.Config.properties

My application runs with no problems, support libraries are correctly setup, it's just the test that I can't seem to get right.

Comment: What's the minSdk for the project? Does the robolectric project have its own AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: from the first guess i'd say thatRoboelectric doesn't apply the theme you've specified in the AndroidManifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who comes across this question, a potential solution can be found - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903155/fragment-testing-error-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-16)

The theme you provide must be a child of `Theme.MaterialComponents`